# Googlemaps Api weird behavior

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, google-maps, api-design

I decided to have a play around with googlemaps and the ISS api to build a basic tracker. I plan on adding a bunch of stuff to this but for now this is kept simple.

The problem i am having is, i can set dummy values in the asp:Labels for Latitude & Longitude then populate a string with them that i can use with google maps.

```
var ISS = { lat: parseFloat(document.getElementById('lblLat').innerText), lng: parseFloat(document.getElementById('lblLong').innerText) };
```

This works, when i then try use the values i get from the json callback even though i can see these when i use console.log(), they do not work.

```
ISS = { lat: data['iss_position']['latitude'], lng: data['iss_position']['longitude'] };
```

I have tried instead of reading directly adding back to the asp:Label's then reading however it does not work either.

What am i doing wrong? I have tried not to add any complexity to this while i toy with googlemaps api but this not working is confusing me as i dont see whats different with dummy values vs what i get from an api.
[image: webpage]

Below is all my code for this page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ISS.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApps.IIS" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <head runat="server">
        <title>ISS Tracker</title>
        <style>
          #map {
            height: 400px;  /* The height is 400 pixels */
            width: 100%;  /* The width is the width of the web page */
           }
          #pageTitle{
              margin: auto;
              padding: 10px;
          }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="pageTitle">
            <h3>ISS Tracker</h3>
            <h4>International Space Station</h4>
        </div>
        <form runat="server">
            <label>Latitude: </label><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLat"/><br />
            <label>Longitude: </label><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLong"/><br />
            <label>Time: </label><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTime" Text="13/02/2020 15:45:00" /><br />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnRefresh" Text="Refresh" onClick="btnRefresh_Click" style="height: 26px" />
            <div id="map"></div>
        </form>
        <script>

            //globals
            var map;
            var ISS;// = { lat: parseFloat(document.getElementById('lblLat').innerText), lng: parseFloat(document.getElementById('lblLong').innerText) };
            var image = 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/goodstuff-no-nonsense/free-space/256/international-space-station-icon.png'

            // Initialize and add the map
            function initMap() {
                // The location of ISS
                $.getJSON('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json?callback=?', function (data) {
                    ISS = { lat: data['iss_position']['latitude'], lng: data['iss_position']['longitude'] }; 
                    console.log("latitude: " + data['iss_position']['latitude'] + " & longitude: " + data['iss_position']['longitude']);
                    document.getElementById('lblLat').innerText = data['iss_position']['latitude'];
                    document.getElementById('lblLong').innerText = data['iss_position']['longitude'];
                });
                // The map, centered at ISS
                map = new google.maps.Map(
                    document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 10, center: ISS });
                // The marker, positioned at ISS
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: ISS,
                    map: map,
                    icon: {
                        url: image,
                        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(128, 128),
                        size: new google.maps.Size(128, 128)
                    }
                });
                marker.position = ISS;

            }

            //Will use later when i want to update
            function moveISS() {
                $.getJSON('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json?callback=?', function (data) {
                    var lat = data['iss_position']['latitude'];
                    var lon = data['iss_position']['longitude'];
                    ISS = { lat: lat, lng: lon }; 
                    document.getElementById('lblLat').innerText = lat;
                    document.getElementById('lblLong').innerText = lon;
                });
                setTimeout(moveISS, 5000);
            } 
        </script>
        <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*****api key *****&callback=initMap">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem is due to when things happen**

Your getJSON call launches and then will return with a data response at some point in the future, however the rest of your code (with an invalid value for ISS) will execute immediately

```js
var map;
var image = 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/goodstuff-no-nonsense/free-space/256/international-space-station-icon.png';

// ISS start position
var ISS  = { lat: 0.0, lng: 0.0 };

function initMap() {
  // create the map and marker before you know where ISS is
  // The map, centered at ISS
   map = new google.maps.Map(
     document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 10, center: ISS });
   // The marker, positioned at ISS
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: ISS,
     map: map,
     icon: {
       url: image,
       scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(128, 128),
       size: new google.maps.Size(128, 128)
     }
   });


}

function updateISS() {
  // The location of ISS
  $.getJSON('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json?callback=?', 
     function (data) {
       ISS = { 
         lat: data['iss_position']['latitude'], 
         lng: data['iss_position']['longitude'] 
       };

       // update the Marker position here
       marker.setPosition(ISS);

       console.log("latitude: " + ISS['lat'] + " & longitude: " + ISS['lng']);
       document.getElementById('lblLat').innerText = ISS['lat'];
       document.getElementById('lblLong').innerText = ISS['lng'];
     });

}

// update ISS position every 5 seconds.
var repeat = setInterval( updateISS, 5000)
```

The above is a first pass at a solution, creating the map and the marker **before** the getJSON call and updating the marker position when the JSON response is obtained.

Also I would note you're using a mixture of JavaScript and JQuery which ain't pretty

Comment: I did not know this. Is there a way to get it to wait?

Comment: More complete solution now in answer

Comment: few minor bugs, and variable names not matching but solid solution to my problem. Thank you.
 it is worth adding
map.setCenter(ISS);

also ISS lng -> lon

The solution below also offers some great improvements but given you replied first i made this the best answer as both are valid but i feel yours is slightly more complete.

Comment: No worries - I was at work so couldn't test my answer in any way

Comment: I based my example on your code, but if I were writing it, I'd also use ES6 instead of 'traditional' JavaScript

Comment: i will look up es6, i just want to learn some more simple things like this improve my skills, im more comfortable as a backend dev with a bit of sql

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't understand something about JS API calls.
When you call  $.getJSON you have callback method which will have a result when data was loaded.
So when you create marker you don't have defined IIS lat/lng coordinates.
Another interesting thing about JS that you must to know - JS is a synchronous language, so your callback will be executed after all operations were done (your last line for the script - marker.position = ISS; ).
Just create a marker in your $.getJSON callback to make it work

I created a working demo which fixes some other errors which are present.

here i display start location - you must convert coordinates to number type:

```
function initMap() {
            // The location of ISS
            $.getJSON('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json?callback=?', function (data) {
                ISS = new google.maps.LatLng(Number(data.iss_position.latitude), Number(data.iss_position.longitude)); 
                console.log("latitude: " + data['iss_position']['latitude'] + " & longitude: " + data['iss_position']['longitude']);
                document.getElementById('lblLat').value = data['iss_position']['latitude'];
                document.getElementById('lblLong').value = data['iss_position']['longitude'];

                // The map, centered at ISS
            map = new google.maps.Map(
                document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 10, center: ISS });
            // The marker, positioned at ISS
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: ISS,
                map: map,
                icon: {
                    url: image,
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(128, 128),
                    size: new google.maps.Size(128, 128)
                }
            });

            });   
        }
```

move marker code (use google classes for location new google.maps.LatLng) :

```
function moveISS() {
            $.getJSON('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json?callback=?', function (data) {
                ISS = new google.maps.LatLng(Number(data.iss_position.latitude), Number(data.iss_position.longitude)); 
                document.getElementById('lblLat').value = data.iss_position.latitude;
                document.getElementById('lblLong').value = data.iss_position.longitude;
                marker.setPosition(ISS);
                map.setCenter(ISS);
            });

            setTimeout(moveISS, 5000);
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cheaterr/41h7tmqb/11/

Comment: i will test this, thank you for explaining. I very rarely do anything with Javascript infact im doing this as a way to learn something i dont work with often. Appreciate the improved code, my code has become a bit messy when i was trying different things to get it to work.

Comment: i tested this and with a couple tweaks to fit it in, works perfectly, i appreciate the time and effort you put into giving an answer. I will endeavour to improve my questions and understanding. Thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome. The best way to prepare some solution in JSFiddle to have quick answer, because to be sure the code must be debugged.

Comment: i will look up JSFiddle. i am very new to javascript having managed to avoid it most of the time i was at university. Now i want to learn it i appreciate been pointed in the right direction. Not sure where to take my little project now. might look up some other apis and see if i can combine data to display something interesting on the map.